# package management via AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

I am trying to remove packages using a cloud formation template.
I have and can install it using the both packages and files structures but I need to remove one and install a different version.
i.e. remove java 1.6 and install java 1.4

Comment: Why don't you just create an AMI with the right packages?

Comment: @ceejayoz That's generally not a good idea because it increase the management overhead by "freezing" the underlying system.  Every time even a minor change is needed, an entirely new AMI has to be created.  It's more flexible to provision at boot.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation templates can execute arbitrary userdata scripts, which means you can do most anything you'd like. Here's one [sophisticated example](http://allanfeid.com/content/using-amazons-cloudformation-cloud-init-chef-and-fog-automate-infrastructure), but you could just as easily refer to this [puppet guide](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Bootstrapping_AWS_CloudFormation) or the CFN [templates page](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/) (the highly available RoR template has some nice UserData examples).